# load environment variable from YAML to java

Tags: java, yaml

First time, I am trying to load the environment variables from YAML file.
Earlier I had an environment variable in a form of `key:value` pair.

```
secrets:
    - env: ${dev:-}
```

The content of the environment `dev` is stored in some other file which is being loaded here.
But now I have multiple environments so I need to pass an array of values to the key.

```
secrets:
    - env: 
      - ${dev:-}
      - ${test:-}
      - ${prod:-}
```

Now, based on the environment `[dev, test, prod]` passed by the user, I want to load the values depending upon the environment.

1. When I get the array for `env` is this going to be an array of string?

Thanks

Comment: Is this YAML coming from a Spring properties file?

Comment: @OneCricketeer No

Comment: Just asking... But yes, you have shown a YAML collection being assigned to the env collection https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963 (making secrets hold a list of lists)

Comment: @OneCricketeer How can I compare the user passed param with the `env` collection? I thought using `${dev:-}` loads the content stored in `dev`

Comment: I don't know what Java library you are using to load this file. `${dev:-}` is a shell expansion format, not YAML specific

Comment: @OneCricketeer So I am trying to compare the environment right? My main question is how do I compare and substitute the value in java file? Let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: And I dont think I can answer that without knowing what Java library you use to load that file... But you could just attach a debugger whereever you parse the file to see what data gets loaded into it

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry, I am not using any java library. Previously, it was an environment variable so when I was doing `${dev:-}` I think the value was being substituted for `env`. But now I cannot do that as I want to compare the environment with the user passed argument.

Comment: Java doesn't have a native YAML parser, so you have to be using something... If you are just reading it as a plain text file, then environment variables are not expanded at all. But that doesn't stop you from still printing out the contents of the file after being read to show that

Comment: Overall, I do suggest you use SpringBoot here, because it does parse YAML and exposes the concept of profiles for getting variables from different runtime environments https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config